# HTML5/Javascript: Content changing without adress changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

I have a question which I haven't been able to find the answer for. I hope you can help me.

I am about to build a simple website, containing text and hyperlinks. I want the site to have the same adress no matter which hyperlink is clicked. For example, if my website is www.website.com - when one clicks a hyperlink, the content of the whole page should change, but the adress should still be www.website.com, instead of www.website.com/hyperlink.html for example. In other words, I want to disable people to use the "back" button to return to an earlier page, and prevent them from navigating the page by writing in the adress bar. They should experience a single page, but still be able to navigate through a lot of changing content through links - which means that if they click the "back"-button, they will be navigated away from the website, and if they refresh the page, it will go back to 'index'. Can you point me in the right direction to which methods might be useful here? Earlier, I would have done it in Flash, and embedded the flash-construction into the website, but as far as I have heard, Flash is not the best solution anymore?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to reinvent frames? Sounds like you just want to load content with Ajax.

Comment: try one page websites that have single page but contain different sections. You can navigate between sections easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, that is not the best idea for SEO.
But that puts aside, you should use javascript to make AJAX call and alter the partial part of your page with the response.

So basically, what you will do is from your home page, capture all link clicked event, and process the request through an AJAX call, and display the result of that call on the same page.

That allow you to refresh a list of item, or a menu, or the entire page if you want.

Since it will be AJAX call, the user won't see any difference in the URL.